# Explaining and deducing the average maximum of an r-element subset of {1,2,...,n}

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I need to deduce and explain this statement:

> Consider all r-element subsets of the set $\left\{1,2,...,n\right\}$. Each of them has a maximum. Deduce that the average maximum of an r-element subset of $\left\{1,2,...,n\right\}$ is precisely $\frac{r}{r+1}(n+1)$

I don't know how to deduce this. Please, help me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: An obvious place to start is to work the problem explicitly for small $n,r$.  After that, perhaps a simple induction will suffice.